# How do I make images responsive using bootstrap4 flexbox?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have section "Top Categories" and I am trying to make the image cards responsive but am not able to achieve it. Not sure what am I missing. I have used flexbox classes from bootstrap 4 but still it doesn't work.

Here is the [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/HebleV/pen/RQOzKK)

Below is the code:

**index.html**

```css
.Top-Categories {
  width: 267px;
  height: 29px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #4a4a4a;
}

.Top-Categories-Img-Card {
  width: 1104px;
  margin-left: 205px;
  margin-right: 205px;
}

.Top-Categories-Img {
  width: 159px;
  height: 238px;
}

.Top-Categories-Label {
  width: 93px;
  height: 15px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #4a4a4a;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="Top-Categories-Img-Card">
  <h3 class="Top-Categories">Top Categories</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
      <div class="">
        <img class="card-img-top Top-Categories-Img" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9h4jk5s6ca0suqu/pic2.jpg?raw=1" alt="Card image">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#" class="Top-Categories-Label">Fun & Recreation</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
      <div class="">
        <img class="card-img-top Top-Categories-Img" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9h4jk5s6ca0suqu/pic2.jpg?raw=1" alt="Card image">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#" class="Top-Categories-Label">Education & Skill Development</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
      <div class="">
        <img class="card-img-top Top-Categories-Img" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9h4jk5s6ca0suqu/pic2.jpg?raw=1" alt="Card image">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#" class="Top-Categories-Label">Informative & Motivational</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
      <div class="">
        <img class="card-img-top Top-Categories-Img" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9h4jk5s6ca0suqu/pic2.jpg?raw=1" alt="Card image">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#" class="Top-Categories-Label">Health & Fitness</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
      <div class="">
        <img class="card-img-top Top-Categories-Img" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9h4jk5s6ca0suqu/pic2.jpg?raw=1" alt="Card image">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#" class="Top-Categories-Label">Kids & Teens</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
      <div class="">
        <img class="card-img-top Top-Categories-Img" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/9h4jk5s6ca0suqu/pic2.jpg?raw=1" alt="Card image">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#" class="Top-Categories-Label">Home Maintenance</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You're missing the card class btw in your code. Can't have a card-body without card. I'm assuming its where <div class=""> is supposed to be. Second of all, your code is responsive. If you switch to a very small screen size, your images will be stacked on top of each other. I tested it in codepen and in my own environment. The only tip I'd give you is wrap your row inside of <div class="container"> or <div class="countainer-fluid">

Comment: Unless you mean your images arent enlarging when they are stacked?

Comment: I am not using class="card" as I didn't want the border but you can still use with card class.

Comment: It's okay you can always override any bootstrap setting, you keep the card but make the border to 0.. Or add your own cash class with border to 0 on the card itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom css hacks (unnecessary hacks) are messing up Bootstrap.

To fix the problem do this:

1. Add the `container` class to the `<section>` and
2. Remove all of your custom css

Now everything will start working as expected and you can start adding custom css line by line to see where your custom css breaks Bootstrap.

Also, you don't need to write classes like `col-sm-12 col-md-2`. You just need `col-md-2` in that case because on screens smaller than `md` it will automatically default to full width i.e. the equivalent of `col-sm-12`.

Comment: Yes you're right my custom css hacks were messing the responsiveness. So I used the inbuilt classes mb,mt for margins and,pl,pr, for Padding. It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a way to make images responsive within a grid.

Everything you need to know can be found in the official documentation of Bootstrap 4. https://getbootstrap.com/

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/720x480" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/720x480" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/720x480" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```